# What are the changes of diamine oxidase (DAO)-activity with different sex hormones?

Tags: endocrinology, testosterone, estrogen

Based on this question: [What happens to a woman if she takes testosterone?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/what-happens-to-a-woman-if-she-takes-testosterone) i have another question and would like to know more - that's because i've stumbled over this:

> DAO activity in tissues of female guinea pigs was determined after the
>   administration of estradiol or progesterone. Estradiol pretreatment
>   elicited significant fall in DAO activity in the liver and specific
>   increase in the uterus. The effect of progesterone was much less
>   pronounced.
>   https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3088928

Let's say the test person is Alice, 20 years old, low DAO activity + histamine intolerance and estrogen dominance.

So, the special question is: If estradiol is involved in an significant fall in DAO activity then what would happen if alice would consume estrogen blockers and something like nebido. I know masculinization and things that are mentioned in the other question, but what exactly could happen to the DAO activity?

Does testosterone have an impact on the dao activity or just the estrogen blockers? And what is with progesterone - how is that involved?